# Librosa audio effects not being processed

Tags: python, librosa

I am trying to make a program that modulates my voice in real-time using Librosa in python. It works when I just pass through the audio, however, when I try to add effects it no longer produces any sound and I just cannot work out what the problem is.

Here is the callback in question:

```
def process_input(self, in_data, frame_count, time_info, flag):
        '''Process the input audio data and play back the modified audio.'''
        # Convert the input audio data to a numpy array
        numpy_array = np.frombuffer(in_data, dtype=np.float32)
        
        # Apply pitch shifting to create a robotic voice effect
        pitch_shifted_audio = librosa.effects.pitch_shift(y=numpy_array, sr=self.RATE, n_steps=4)
        
        # Apply a low-pass filter to attenuate high frequencies
        filtered_audio = librosa.effects.preemphasis(pitch_shifted_audio, coef=0.95)
        
        # Convert the modified audio data back to bytes
        out_data = filtered_audio.astype(np.float32).tobytes()

        # Play back the modified audio
        self.output_stream.write(out_data)

        return None, pyaudio.paContinue
```

I have tried setting specific audio devices instead of using the defaults and I have tried removing the effects. The audio definitely works.

When I fill the space between each effect with print statements I can see that it does not get past the first, pitch-shift, effect. But when I remove it it doesn't get past the preemphasis either.